# Where to insert the google conversion code when there is no thank you page?

Tags: php, google-ads-api, contact-form

I will paste the code I have on my contact-form.php file, where I think the conversion code should go.

The thing is I don't have a thank you page and I don't know where exactly do I have to paste the google conversion code (in what file and in what code line).

I have read other conversations, but I don't fully understand what I have to do. 
Here is my landing page: http://crediflash.com.mx/pide/tu_credito_ya.html
Thanks!!!

```
<?php
$to="mr.rivers220@gmail.com";/*rro@quintaimagen.com.mx*/
$subject="Message from the Landing - Contact Form ";
$date=date("l, F jS, Y");
$time=date("h:i A");
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
$caoch=$_REQUEST['caoch'];
$file=$_REQUEST['file'];

$msg="
Mensaje enviado de la landing en la fecha $date, a la hora: $time.\n
First Name: $name\n
Email: $email\n
Phone: $phone\n
Caoch: $caoch\n
File: $file
";
if($email=="") {
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
<a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
<strong>¡Error!</strong> Favor de llenar todos los campos.
</div>";
} else {
mail($to,$subject,$msg,"From:".$email);
echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
<a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
<strong>¡Gracias! Nos comunicaremos contigo</strong>
</div>";
}

?>
```

Here is how the button looks in the HTML file:

```
<button type="submit" value="¡Pedir información ya!" 
class='btn submit sub-form' name="submit">¡Pedir información ya!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to output it where the user has converted.

This would appear to be in the `else` block that's saying `¡Gracias!` in your case.

Comment: Thank you, @ceejayoz!! Should I put the code right between the contigo</strong> and the </div>?

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to ruin the functionality of the form by pasting some code where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Yup between the </strong> and the </div> should be ok.  Be careful with 'echo' here - you'll need to make sure that when you paste in the conversion code that its going to echo out ok without any errors.  Get the Google Tag Assistant extension to help validate that it is ok.

Comment: @matt1, I tried it yesterday, and the contact form stopped working. D: Should I add the code to the html of the landing page? I added the HTML code at the end of my question.